# ipset add white_list_net_port 128.0.0.0/1,udp:443-444 error

Tags: iptables, netfilter, ipset

ipset v7.1, protocol version: 7 When I execute 'ipset add white_list_net_port 128.0.0.0/1,udp:443-444', the system reports 'ipset v7.1: Hash is full, cannot add more elements',white_list_net_port is stuffed with elements. But when I execute 'ipset add white_list_net_port 128.0.0.0/1,udp:443' and 'ipset add white_list_net_port 128.0.0.0/1,udp:444',it's fine.

ipset v6.29 doesn't have this problem!

I'm looking forward to figuring out what this is and how to fix it, because I want to express all IP and I merged the port